# Non-greedy matching in webapp2 routes?

Tags: python, webapp2

I have two routes in a Python app that I'm working on, and I can't seem to make the matching work correctly.  The routes look like:

```
webapp2.Route('/(.*?)/(.*?)', grouploader.Loader),
webapp2.Route(r'/edit/(.*?)/(.*?)', handler='grouploader.Editor'),
```

I'd like for urls like `/a/b` to go to the first and `/edit/a/b` to go to the second.  Apparently the matches here are greedy, since the first rule always matches, returning me `"edit/a"` and `"b"` for the two values.  Is there a way to make this work, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the routes, and don't use lazy matching, you have another much better tool for that:

```
webapp2.Route('/edit/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', handler = 'grouploader.Editor');
webapp2.Route('/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', grouploader.Loader);
```

Comment: That results in 404s for both URLs.

Comment: Are you sure there are no trailing slashes? Regexes match, that is for sure

Comment: From the GAE log: INFO     2013-05-19 23:26:58,187 server.py:585] default: "GET /edit/a/b HTTP/1.1" 404 154

Comment: I think I might have sorted it out.  The regexes have to be wrapped in <: > for GAE.  Thanks for the help!